# Lookup tables and performance

Tags: mysql, database-design

I am using 6 lookup tables in my mysql database. There will be frequent insert,update and delete queries in the db. Will that badly affect the performance. Do I need to save the data as it is without using lookup tables?

Comment: Add details, tables structure, etc. As it is, there is not enough information in the question to be answered. But why don't you test?

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing a look-up to these reference tables for every DML statement, it *could* be a performance issue - depending on *many things* (hardware allocated to your database, volume of data being manipulated, volume of reference data, number of look-ups per DML, indexing on reference tables, whether or not you can combine a simpl look-up in another DML statement,...) that I just don't know about your system.

One strategy to avoid such problems is to cache the data from look-up tables in your application when the application starts up. Then your application doesn't have to make a database call, it can do the look-up in a local hashtable (or some other structure with very good look-up time). You could also use something like memcached to store the reference data. It's also sometimes useful to add functionlity to your application so that the caches can be reloaded from the reference tables "live" (while the application is already running). This is very useful when testing changes that are dependent on the reference data in an application that has a long start-up time.